# Creating a Device Context for a Monitor in Mirror mode

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been through a ton of documentation on the issue and I can't seem to find anything to indicate this is possible.

I typically use this function to create my HDC
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490(v=VS.85).aspx

I've checked about every nook and cranny from the registry to WMI and their doesn't seem to be anyway to create and HDC for a monitor in clone mode.

I was hoping to be able create an HDC because without that you can't modify the montior's look up table or use it's DDC interface.

If there is a newer cleaner way to modify the LUT or access DDC I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
EnumDisplayDevices(...);
```

and get the name of the display device and pass it to the CreateDC function.

or

```
EnumDisplayMonitors(...)
GetMonitorInfo(...)
```

functions to get the dimensions of the monitors.
You should draw in the limits of the second monitors virtual area. The virtual area is the two monitors combined... I guess the rectangles (coordinates) are different, even though you are mirroring. I didn't check it.

Comment: For followers, this worked for me for something similar, just be aware you have to use the "display device" name not the monitor name...wait what's the monitor name even used for? (with EnumDisplayDevices)

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with GDI contexts, [SetWorldTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not trying to mirror the content on the monitor, i'm trying to get the hDC for a second monitor that is mirroring the primary monitor.

Comment: Hm... I did some investigation: CreateDC("DISPLAY", "\\\\.\\DISPLAY2", NULL, NULL) returns non-null ('\\.\DISPLAY3', in contrary, returns NULL on two-monitor setup), but painting to that device, obviously displays nothing. Still it might be helpful if you are trying to access the monitor's DDC. At least you can open the device...